# PostgreSQL COPY command: How to suppress timezone info for "TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE"?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am extracting the data from `PostgreSQL` in order to load it to some other database. This database unfortunately does not recognize timezone info in timestamps. Iam using python adn `psycopg2` to extract data to `csv`. Even if I set timezone on a session level,  I am getting timestamps in this format:

```
    def to_csv(self, table, fname, sep = '|'):
    cur = self._conn.cursor()
    #cur.execute('select * from {}'.format(table))
    log.info('Unloading table {} to file {}'.format(table, fname))
    f = open(fname, 'w')
    cur.execute("SET LOCAL TIMEZONE='UTC'")
    cur.execute("SET datestyle='ISO'")

    cur.copy_to(f, table, sep)
    cur.close()
    f.close()
```

> 2015-08-18 12:54:29.528**+00**

How do I remove +00 in this case? I would like to avoid parsing the file with regexps or specifying select statements and transforming column types. Looking for some session level setting if possible.

Comment: How about casting your column with `timestamptz` to just simple `timestamp` without time zone before extracting it to a file?

Comment: Thanks! Yes I also came to this idea as a workaround.  Cast it to char actually.